# How can I parse a CSV file using VB.NET using CarriageReturn and LineFeed?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I need to parse a CSV file using VB.NET using CarriageReturn and LineFeed as third column contains commas. CSV header is ID, Name, Description.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ID As String
        Dim Element As String
        Dim Description As String

        Dim tfp As New TextFieldParser("Z:\Downloads\test.csv")
        tfp.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited

        tfp.ReadLine() ' skip header
        While tfp.EndOfData = False
            Dim fields = tfp.ReadFields()
            ID = fields(0)
            Element = fields(1)
            Description = fields(2)

            CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = fields
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If a field value contains delimiters then it should be wrapped in quotes. Otherwise it's not really CSV data. The TextFieldParser can handle quoted data.

Comment: Are you saying that the third column contains CR and LF? Or are you saying that sometimes the line ending is CR and sometimes it is LF?

Comment: `CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = fields`  It doesn't make sense to do this inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextFieldParser` class from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`
This class helps to read structured text files,

Refer the below code for reference :

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim filePath As String = "path\to\your\file.csv"
        ParseCsvFile(filePath)
    End Sub

    Sub ParseCsvFile(filePath As String)
        Try
            Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filePath)
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
                parser.SetDelimiters(",")

                ' Skip the header
                parser.ReadLine()

                While Not parser.EndOfData
                    Dim fields As String() = parser.ReadFields()

                    If fields.Length >= 3 Then
                        Dim id As String = fields(0)
                        Dim name As String = fields(1)
                        Dim description As String = fields(2)

                        ' Now you can use id, name, and description as needed
                        Console.WriteLine($"ID: {id}, Name: {name}, Description: {description}")
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: With the test data I used, the description field is truncated if it contains a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Given that first line is a header and that neither ID nor Element can contain a comma, you could use brute force:

```
  Dim DataLine As Boolean
  Dim FileSpec = "F:\temp\csvtest.txt"
  Dim lines = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileSpec).Split(CChar(vbCr))
  For Each L In lines
     If DataLine Then     'skip header
        Dim a = L.Trim.Split(","c)
        Dim ID = a(0), Element = a(1), Description = a(2)
        For i = 3 To a.Length - 1
           Description &= "," & a(i)        'replace the missing comma
        Next
        'finally, do something with the values
        Dim t = ID & "/" & Element & "/" & Description
     Else
        DataLine = True
     End If
  Next
```

Comment: String.Split has an overload which lets you tell it the maximum number of parts to split the string into, so the `For i` loop would not be needed. However, the OP has not yet told us if a value can take more than one line.

Comment: The For i loop's purpose is to capture the full description field regardless of the number of commas (and therefore, parts) that it might contain.  As to multiple lines, this approach assumes one line per record, delineated by a CR.  A CR in the description would break it.  :)  As pointed out above, the ideal solution is to have a properly formatted csv file to start with.  Unfortunately, we can't always work in an ideal world.  Thanks for the comment, Andrew.

Comment: You might find it useful to know that you could have written `Dim a = L.Split({","c}, 3)` and removed the inner loop. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

Comment: Finally, I see what you mean.  I misunderstood the count parameter.  Thanks for pushing.  Always nice to learn a little more.